# Does an active pilot based outside the US require a flight review to maintain FAA currency?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

If a pilot is a holder of both Canadian and FAA commercial pilot certificates and is flying regularly in Canada, does this pilot still require a Flight Review to maintain currency of their FAA certificate?

Comment: Are you in a WINGS program?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Comment: Transport Canada tried to impose its own version of biennial flight reviews in the late 80s, but after a storm of opposition from the GA community, it was watered down to a requirement to take a short at-home self study test or attend a safety seminar every two years.

Answer (score 5):

FAR part 61.56 ( [[U.S.]Flight Review](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_165) ) requires a U.S.flight review (or authorized alternative - see below), for anyone operating an "N" numbered airplane within the U.S. (when using a U.S. certificate/or U.S. certificate based on a foreign certificate), even if that person is current in another country for which he/she also holds a certificate.

See also, FAR 61.75 ([Private pilot certificate issued on the basis of a foreign pilot license.](http://61.75%20%20%20Private%20pilot%20certificate%20issued%20on%20the%20basis%20of%20a%20foreign%20pilot%20license.))

See also this FAA Legal Interpretation which relates to your question:
[need for Flight Review for holder of U.S. cert based on foreign cert in accordance with FAR 61.75](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2013/collins%20-%20(2013)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf)

NOTE: In accordance with FAR 61.56 there are various types of  pilot proficiency checks or practical tests, etc. that may be substituted for a flight review (i.e. see FAR 61.56(d)-(f))